# Run script on remote machine via telnet (not SSH)

Tags: shell, telnet, remote-access

I need to somehow run a script which resides on a remote machine running Ubuntu.
SSH or any other connection type that requires complex encryption is not possible.
The client that will connect to the remote machine is only capable of opening a port and sending and receiving strings.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Why is SSH not possible? Allowing unauthenticated access is a pretty massive security hole, especially if you're allowing remote clients to run scripts.

Comment: The client machine is not natively capable of SSH. I would have to write an SSH client myself in the native language of the client machine. I can use username password access control but nothing too complex. I can also adjust security on the server side to restrict access as much as possible.

Comment: OK, just so long as you have a good reason :)

Comment: So Cameron, can it be done via telnet?

Comment: Maybe. It depends a lot on the capabilities of your client. A quick scan of the telnet man page doesn't indicate that it supports reading commands from a script, but it might work if you pipe commands to it (I haven't tried), or maybe your version of telnet does support scripting. I guess there's no fundamental reason why telnet wouldn't work - it's just a remote shell - but the specifics will depend on your version of telnet, your client capabilities (if it's a *nix system things will be easier), and the complexity of what you want to do (e.g. running one script is easier than several).

Answer (score 0):

Why is your remote Ubuntu machine "not natively capable of SSH". That's nonsense.

But if you want a solution, use *expect* - it can run ftp/telnet or any other terminal-based application. It can react to different input, and type in a password.

There are python and perl-based packages that also do this.

Comment: It's the client that is not natively capable of SSH.